# Remove Items From Ruby Hashes of Array

Tags: ruby, arrays, hash

```
data = {'results' => [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
        'weather' => ["bad", "bad", "bad", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "bad", "bad"]}
```

results has ten entries, and weather has ten entries, they are aligned and correspond to each other.  how can i delete from the variable data two entries from weather, and the corresponding entry from results, where weather == "bad"  ?

Comment: Do you want to delete all entries in `weather` that is `bad` and corresponding entries in `results`?

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev No only 2 *bad*, and it corresponding *weather* OP mentioned..

Comment: I didnt get which two, though. Any?

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev You would iterate through `weather` array, then if you found *bad*, delete it and also delete the corresponding entry from *results* array. But deletion will be happened only twice.

Comment: @ArupRakshit So, this is simple, iterate `weather` with index and use this index for `results`.

Comment: @YevgeniyAnfilofyev Go ahead then... :-)

Comment: @ArupRakshit just did it ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand it right, you should find first occurence of 'bad' in `weather` array, get an index of this occurence and delete elements in both arrays (and do it twice):

```
data = {'results' => [1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0], 
        'weather' => ["bad", "bad", "bad", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "bad", "bad"]}

2.times do
  idx = data['weather'].index('bad')
  data['weather'].delete_at(idx)
  data['results'].delete_at(idx)
end

p data
```

Result:

```
{"results"=>[1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 0],
 "weather"=>["bad", "good", "good", "good", "good", "good", "bad", "bad"]}
```

Comment: thanks.  from your post i learned the X.times syntax, the delete_at function, and the index function (or in ruby i guess they are methods?).  much simpler than the stuff i was trying to do.

Answer (score 0):

The following works:

```
index_array = []
counter = 0
data['weather'].each_with_index do |a,i|
  if a=="bad" and counter !=2
    data['results'][i] = nil
    data['weather'][i] = nil
    counter = counter + 1
  end
end

data['results'] = data['results'].compact
data['weather'] = data['weather'].compact
```